# Calculate sum in several fields with StatisticsDefinition()

Tags: javascript, arcgis-js-api, esri-maps

I have built a widget in WebAppBuilder for ArcGis where you can select an area and see the information that is within it, the selection is based on the radius you choose, in this case between 100 and 300 metres.

I'd like to add a functionality so I would like to create from the first query result the sum of the four fields into the attribute table.

I found out on the API the Statitics Definition class so I used with the result from the first query but it is not working.

I'd appreciate if someone could give some advice about the sum query.

Thanks in advace.

Below the code :

```
 var myQuery = new Query();
         myQuery.where = "1 = 1";
         myQuery.outFields = ["POB_TOT", "EDAD0015", "EDAD1664","EDAD65_"];

         myQuery.returnGeometry = true;
         var myQueryTask = new QueryTask(_poblacion);

           myQuery.geometry = circle;
           myQuery.spatialRelationship = Query.SPATIAL_REL_INTERSECTS;


    var sumfields = new StatisticDefinition();
          sumfields.statisticType = "sum";

          sumfields.onStatisticField = "POB_TOT", "EDAD0015", "EDAD1664","EDAD65_";

          myQuery.outStatistics = sumfields;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see there are different workaround for this.  you can not pass multiple fields However you can pass multiple `outStatistics` in your case.

So below the sample in your case-

**Example-**

```
var sumfields1 = new StatisticDefinition();
sumfields1.statisticType = "sum";
sumfields1.onStatisticField = "POB_TOT"; //any one numeric field
sumfields1.outStatisticFieldName = "sum_Pob_Tot";

var sumfields2 = new StatisticDefinition();
sumfields2.statisticType = "sum";
sumfields2.onStatisticField = "EDAD0015"; //any one numeric field
sumfields2.outStatisticFieldName = "sum_EDAD0015"; 

var sumfields3 = new StatisticDefinition();
sumfields3.statisticType = "sum";
sumfields3.onStatisticField = "EDAD1664"; //any one numeric field
sumfields3.outStatisticFieldName = "sum_EDAD1664";    
.
.
.
.
.
myQuery.outStatistics = [sumfields1, sumfields2, sumfields3 .... ];
```

This might solve your problem.

Feel free to shoot your further queries.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I am afraid that we can't pass multiple fields in `onStatisticField`.

This is design in such a way that it will add(in case of **sum**) all values of a specific field.

***outStatistics is only supported on layers/tables where supportsStatistics is true.***

**Example-**

```
require([
  "esri/tasks/query", "esri/tasks/StatisticDefinition", ... 
], function(Query, StatisticDefinition, ... ) {
  var query = new Query();
  var statisticDefinition = new StatisticDefinition();
  statisticDefinition.statisticType = "sum";
  statisticDefinition.onStatisticField = "POP2000";
  statisticDefinition.outStatisticFieldName = "TotalPop";

  query.outStatistics = [statisticDefinition];
  ...
});
```

**Sources-**

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/query-amd.html#outstatistics

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/statisticdefinition-amd.html#outstatisticfieldname

**In your case-**

```
var sumfields = new StatisticDefinition();
sumfields.statisticType = "sum";
sumfields.onStatisticField = "POB_TOT"; //any one numeric field
sumfields.outStatisticFieldName = "sum_Pob_Tot";   

myQuery.outStatistics = [sumfields];
```

Note- However you need to verify first that your GIS layer is enabled for `StatisticDefinition` or not.

If you are still facing issue then share your GIS layer.

**Hoping this will help you :)**